# starting nginx docker container with custom nginx config file

Tags: docker, nginx

**My Requirements**

- I am working on a Windows 10 machine
- I have my test app running on  http://localhost:3000/
- I need to have a reverse proxy setup so http://localhost:80 redirects to http://localhost:3000/ ( i will be adding further rewrite rules when i get the basic setup up and running)

**Steps**

I am following instructions from

- https://www.docker.com/blog/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/

I'm trying to create a container (name = mynginx1) specifying my own nginx conf file

```
$ docker run --name mynginx1 -v C:/zNGINX/testnginx/conf:/etc/nginx:ro -P -d nginx
```

where "C:/zNGINX/testnginx/conf" contains the file "default.conf" and its contents are

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

}
```

A container ID is returned, but "docker ps" does not show it running.

Viewing the container logs using "docker logs mynginx1"  shows the following error

```
2020/03/30 12:27:18 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 errors in what i was doing

(1) In the conf file, I was using "proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;"
"localhost" in the container is the CONTAINER host, not MY computer.  Therefore this needed changing to

```
proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000;
```

(2) the path to copy my config file to on the container was not right, i needed to add "conf.d"

```
docker run --name mynginx1 -v C:/zNGINX/testnginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro -P -d nginx
```

The documentation I was reading (multiple websites) did not mention adding the "conf.d" directory on the end of the path.  However if you view the "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" file there is a clue on the last line

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

The "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;" indicates that it loads any file ended in ".conf" from the "/etc/nginx/conf.d/" directory.